# How to fix y-axis guidelines in place while the markers that overflows are pushed down

Tags: reactjs, graph, plotly, plotly.js

I'm using Plotly.js in a React codebase.
So, what I'm trying to do it is basically what you can see in the image:

[image: Expected Behaviour]

I want the y-axis guidelines to stay fixed in place and whenever a value overflows the highest value from the guidelines, then it would be squished/resized down.

But this is what is happening at the moment:

[image: Current Behaviour]

So far I tried adding the following settings to the yaxis layout config:

`fixedrange: true`

`range: [0, 45], // set the fixed range of the y-axis`

`automargin: true, // add margins around the fixed range of the y-axis`

`autosize: true,`